# Embed ReactJS into Flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, flutter-web

**Background:**
We have a ReactJS Web app. We are planning to move to Flutter when expanding the app with more new features.

**Question 1**: What is the best way to embed the existing ReactJS web into Flutter Web without rewrite ReactJS code in Dart?

**Question 2**: If the ReactJS app uses Web APIs (such as Windows), is there any way to embed that in Flutter iOS and Android, in addition to WebView?